# Programmatically logging in to surveymonkey api

Tags: c#, api, oauth-2.0, surveymonkey

Is there a way to programmatically log in to the survey monkey api? I have been tasked with creating a c# application that retrieves survey responses and want to do the authentication from my code, is it possible?

I saw another post that oauth is not suitable for programmatic authentication, is there a work around at all to auto-login to the surveymonkey api?

Comment: after further research it looks as though the only viable approach right now is something like the following:
- Create interface to execute surveymonkeys OAuth2 process and then store the resulting long lived token in our database for use on all the api calls. The interface could be executed by an admin sporadically or as needed to update the long lived token. This is with the understanding that the surveymonkey long lived access token could functionality could change in the future.
If this is inaccurate or there is another way, feel free to correct me.

Comment: Currently tokens have no expiry, but then can still be revoked on the account side. You will want to handle the error 'Client revoked access' when this happens by alerting an admin to recreate the access token.  This will then also work for if the access token expiry ever changes.